# Django, Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' when trying remove an object from manytomany

Tags: django, post, cart, wagtail

I'm working on a mockup e-commerce site using Django and wagtail CMS. I'm running into problems removing items to my cart app.

I'm using a POST method which updates the cart based on a product id. It works as a toggle, if object in cart: remove else: add. 
It works fine on the product page but when I try to remove on the cart page I get ValueError at /cart/update/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
It seems as if the product id isn't getting passed?

This is the HTML for the button which triggers the POST method

```html
<form method='POST' action='{% url "cart:update" %}' class="form"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ self.id }}" />
        {% if incart %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md my-0 p btn-sm" type="submit">
            Remove
        </button>
        {% else %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md my-0 p" type="submit">Add
            to cart
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>

        </button>
        {% endif %}


</form>
```

the 
`{{ self.id }}` variable comes from the product page model. using a wagtail Page model.

The page model

```py
class ProductDetailPage(Page):

    def get_url(self):
        return self.url


    productImage = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        blank = False,
        null = True,
        on_delete = models.SET_NULL
    )

    productPrice = models.FloatField(
        null = False,
        blank = False,
        default = 0

    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel("productImage"),
        FieldPanel("productPrice")
    ]
```

And this is my cart view

```py
def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    if product_id is not None:
        product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if product_obj in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.remove(product_obj)
        else:
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

Comment: Herre `product_id` is the *empty* string. Does your template have a `self` variable?

Comment: @willem-van-onsem yes i should have clarified, the self.ID is from the product page model. I will update. Thanks.

Comment: There is problem in `remove()` method. `cart_obj.products.remove(product_obj)`, please `print(product_obj)` and give us it's value.

Comment: @gachdavit when i run ```print(product_obj)``` it returns the title of the product. in this case it returns shoe.

Comment: it returns Django's model object, yes ?

Comment: @gachdavit yes it returns the title of the object which was queried.

Comment: If you delete `remove()` method at all, everything works fine ?

Comment: Can you add the error trace?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML ,use `<input>` tag two separate ways:

```
{% if in_cart %}
  <Button>…</Button>
  <Input type='hidden' value='…' />
{% else %}
  <Button>…</Button>
  <Input type='hidden '…' />
{% endif %}`
```

[As seen in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNorQ.png)